# Mac OS X app crash with Code Signature Invalid error

Tags: macos, sandbox

I write an app for OS X and when I archive the app and export it as an application and try to open then it crashes with Code Signature Invalid error.

I have created Mac App Distribution, Mac Installer Distribution, Developer ID Application, Developer ID Installer certificates and distribution provisiong profile. The app is sandboxed and I tested it on Mavericks.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0x7fff71ce90a8 (cr2):
    __LINKEDIT             00007fff67043000-00007fff67057000 [   80K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /usr/lib/dyld
--> Submap                 00007fff70000000-00007fff80000000 [256.0M] r--/rwx SM=PRV   process-only VM submap
unused shlib __DATA    00007fff708d3000-00007fff730dc000 [ 40.0M] rw-/rw- SM=COW  system shared lib __DATA not used by this process

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x00007fff66fd1028 _dyld_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000000000000000d  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x00007fff5eda9d30
  r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff66fd1028  rfl: 0x0000000000000201  cr2: 0x00007fff71ce90a8

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x020000f4
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
0x7fff66fd0000 -     0x7fff67003817  dyld (???) <D1DFCF3F-0B0C-332A-BCC0-87A851B570FF> /usr/lib/dyld

External Modification Summary:
Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by this process:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by all processes on this machine:
task_for_pid: 47204
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 1299
```

There is something wrong with the distribution provisioning profile. When I set none or mac team provisioning profile for release then it works. I use iCloud and In-App Purchase.

The problem started when I enabled iCloud or In-App Purchase. If I disable them, then everything works. If I enable one of them, then my provisioning profile is set to none and it works, but when I change it to my distribution profile then stop working.

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Show a copy of the error that you are getting.   Also, double-check the `Code Signing` setting in your Xcode project to make sure the signature is being applied correctly for each of your build types.

Comment: I checked and I think everything is ok. I have Code Signing Identity set to 3rd Party Mac Developer Application and Provisioning Profile to Distribution Provisioning Profile I created.

Comment: I have also Other Code Signing Flags set to --deep, maybe this is a problem?

Comment: sorry for bumping this old question. but do you finally successfully do it? i got the similar problem with yours

Answer (score 4):

You may not have a problem at all. Read:
[Technical Q&A QA1884](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1884/_index.html)
Testing Distribution Builds of Mac Apps

According to that, you are NOT supposed to be able to create installer packages on your own.  You are to make a package and check it via the terminal but it WILL NOT RUN.

By the way there is an error in said tech report.  You may have to include the full-path to the app, so the command:

```
sudo installer -store -pkg Sample.pkg -target /
```

Should be instead something like:

```
sudo installer -store -pkg /user/yourname/desktop/Sample.pkg -target /
```

> Above example assumes your `installer.pkg` is on the desktop.

If you get all passes then you are good.

Drove me crazy, too, because the last App I uploaded (in June) just installed pkg without a problem and the App it installed worked.

Comment: Your answer was a big help. Thanks. For others, here's the link to QA1884 https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1884/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you build this as a beta version which can only run on certain devices? I encountered this exact error when I got a new Mac and forgot to install my beta tester certificates.

I also had some trouble when configuring my profiles. When I found the configuration that worked, I created this screenshot, so that I won’t forget. Maybe it helps:

[image: Screenshot of developer profiles]

Edit: Also make sure to codesign all frameworks that you are compiling yourself. Each framework has to be signed seperately.

Comment: No, I compiled it with distribution certificate for all devices. I use, except Apple framework, framework for Dropbox and Google API Client framework. How should I that signed?

Comment: The problem started when I enabled iCloud or In-App Purchase. If I disable them, then everything works. If I enable one of them, then my provisioning profile is set to none and it works, but when I change it to my distribution profile then stop working.

Comment: I have neither signed the Dropbox framework nor the Google one. I guess you’ve created a workspace and then added the frameworks there? If you compile them, you can click on them in the Xcode sidebar (⌘+1) and will find their code signing options.

Yes, this is a provisioning profile.

I haven’t worked with InApp nor iCloud yet. Can you just enable one of them and see which creates the error?

Comment: I think there is no problem with Dropbox or Google framework, because it works when I disable iCloud, so I think this is only when I use iCloud.

Comment: Hey @BartoszBialecki. iCloud is not support on non-MAS apps as you can see here https://developer.apple.com/osx/distribution/#outside. Did you found any other way to distribute a beta of your iCloud enabled Mac App before submitting it to the MAS?

Comment: @maremmle my app is not distributed outside MAS.

Comment: @BartoszBialecki I was asking for you way to distribute a beta version before it will be in MAS. For this it would need to be outside MAS.

Comment: Ok I understand now but unfortunately I have no idea. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I've had related problems to this, in my case it was because I was using an old version of macOS and Xcode, that didn't have the newer Apple Worldwide Developer Relations certificate installed.

You can install it yourself by downloading it from https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/.