# Code Signing a Mac OS X App for Ad-Hoc Beta Distribution (with HockeyApp)

Tags: xcode, macos, hockeyapp

I have a Mac OS X app, which is properly provisioned in both debug and release mode. That is, I can build & run on my computer in debug mode, or Archive it and successfully submit to the AppStore. However, I'd like to distribute Beta versions of my app to testers (via [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net), FWIW).

The first thing I tried was building it for Achiving with my AppStore Distribution provisioning profile. When I tried to run the resulting app on a different computer, I got a `Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)` crash immediately upon launching. This looks very similar to this question: [Mac OS X app crash with Code Signature Invalid error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994343/mac-os-x-app-crash-with-code-signature-invalid-error)

When I tried provisioning the Archive with my debug profile, instead, I was able to successfully run it on the other machine... but only if I added the other machine's UUID to the debug provisioning profile and installed this profile on the target device. Obviously, this is not an ideal flow for my Beta process: testers would have to collect their UUIDs, send them to me, and then I'd have to cut a new build with a new profile.

So, my question: how can I provision the archive for Beta deployment, so that my testers can just download & run the app without providing a UUID of their OS X device? Alternatively, if I **must** collect UUIDs, is  there any streamlined way to go about this (e.g. through HockeyApp) to minimize pain for my testers?

Answer (score 2):

Since you also asked that in our (HockeyApp) support forum, I'll post my answer here too for completeness (see http://support.hockeyapp.net/discussions/problems/18233-code-signing-a-mac-os-x-app-for-ad-hoc-beta-distribution):

There are multiple options:

1. Use Developer-ID signed beta distribution
   Instead of provisioning the app, only sign it with your developer id and share that one.
2. Use provisioned beta distribution
   This requires you to collect all mac UUIDs of your testers Macs (limited to 100 devices). Testers have to register their Mac on HockeyApp so you can collect the UUIDs to add them to your provisioning profile. You then need to either provide a new build with the new profile or only upload the profile and the new testers have to download and install that before downloading the app.

Comment: Is the second method preferable for iCloud-enabled apps? Or does it not make a difference?

Comment: iCloud can not be used with developer-ID signed apps. You need to sandbox them and use Apples provisioning system for beta and the App Store.

Comment: Thanks. I've been looking, and haven't found any clear instructions for AdHoc distribution for the Mac App Store. When I try to create a distribution provisioning profile on the developer portal, it only offers 2 options: Development, and Mac App Store (no "Distribution"). For Mac App Store, when I import the profile into Xcode, it shows up as "3rd party Mac Developer Application" ... is that the right way? My hunch was this refers to something else, like when you distribute the app directly from your website without MAS? I plan to use Hockey to do the adhoc testing, if that makes a difference

Comment: As far as I know you need to use development profiles since there is no `Ad-Hoc` distribution profile for the Mac.

Comment: Consistently getting `com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement is not allowed` problems. Have tried developer profiles and App Store profiles; neither seem to work. The archiving part works, but not after I export the application.

Comment: You might want to create a new question asking for help. Comments of other questions shouldn't be used for new issues.